# set Button text programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to set text to `Buttons` through Javascript but the value on each button just says `setText(letters)`. I want each `Button` to contain a random letter in my array `letters`. Anybody know what I need to change in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"];

function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
      count = +target.dataset.count;

   target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
   target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
}

function setText(tiles){
      return tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)];
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = setText(letters);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<input type="button" id="button0" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button1" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button3" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

</div>

<div>
<input type="button" id="button4" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button5" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button6" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button7" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="button" id="button8" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button9" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button10" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button11" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="button" id="button12" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button13" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button14" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />

<input type="button" id="button15" value="setText(letters)" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" onclick="setColor(event)"; data-count="1" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `value="setText(letters)"` you are not executing `setText` function but simply setting the text `setText(letters)`. You need some kind of code that sets the input values programmatically like this one:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function setText(tiles){
    return tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)];
}

window.onload = function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].value = setText(letters);
    }
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zjh8ybva/1/)

Comment: ??  He's not exeuting anything with the value tag, just outputting the text in it. Can you execute js from the value tag ? I was trying earlier and couldn't. How do you do it. ###  EDIT ### Now you've edited your post to say not executing...

Comment: @Billy Nope. I was trying to say that the OP is not executing anything when assigning `setText(letters)` to the `value` attribute. ### EDIT ### Yep. I forgot the not. But I think the context helped to deduce it was a typo :). Thanks, anyway.

Comment: it works in your demo, but for some reason it is not working in my code. Can yo please take a look at my edited code above. Maybe you can find the problem?

Comment: @user2456977 Check the updated code. You need to run the code once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function on `onclick` event, call it with `setText(this)`. That way you can set the `value` attribute of the `input` element that was clicked.

To get a random letter from the array `letters` , you can get a random number from `0` to `3` and use it as a random index.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/p3e7cskL/3/)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button0" value="Change" style="color:black; width: 50px; height: 50px" onclick="setText(this)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Change" style="color:black; width: 50px; height: 50px" onclick="setText(this)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Change" style="color:black; width: 50px; height: 50px" onclick="setText(this)"; data-count="1" />
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Change" style="color:black; width: 50px; height: 50px" onclick="setText(this)"; data-count="1" />
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var inpts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i = 0; i < inpts.length; i++) {
    inpts[i].value = letters[Math.round(Math.random() * (letters.length - 1))];
    var count = inpts[i].dataset.count;
    inpts[i].style.backgroundColor = count == 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
    inpts[i].dataset.count = count == 1 ? 0 : 1;
}
function setText(e) {
    var count = e.dataset.count;
    e.style.backgroundColor = count == 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
    e.dataset.count = count == 1 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: I have the buttons change color "onClick". Can I execute two methods "onClick"?

Comment: function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
      count = +target.dataset.count;

   target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
   target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
}

Comment: 'target' is a variable defined in 'setColor'. 'dataset' is a predefined word in Javascript I believe

Comment: The target event property returns the element that triggered the event.
it works fine on my computer..

Comment: this is nice but the buttons change text every time i click. I want them to be set once and stay that way

Comment: @user2456977 - Okay, Check out my updated answer. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The oroblem is that you are trying to use the value (value="setText(letters)") for the button. But infact you are putting the random value that should be into the text attribute - but never 'calling' the text value. I would assume that you should either call the attribute or add a return statement to the function?